# linux clone() succeed,but the child was crashed

Tags: c, linux

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 65536


int a = 0;
int readfd = -1;
int writefd = -1;
int pipe_fd[2];


int test2(void *data)
{
//    printf("it is working\n");
    int n = 1;
    int pos = 0;
    int log_fd = 1;
    char buf[512];
    char log_buf[1024];
    memset(buf,'\0',512);
    memset(log_buf,'\0',1024);

    a = 200;

    log_fd = open("./log.txt",O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
    if(log_fd < 0)
        exit(-1);

    sleep(5);
    if((n = read(readfd,buf,512) ) <= 0)
    {
        sprintf(log_buf,"read error\n");
        write(log_fd,log_buf,strlen(log_buf));
        exit(-1);
    }


    exit(0);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = -1;
    printf("in the main\n");
    void *stack=malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    a = 100;

    if(pipe(pipe_fd) < 0 )
        printf("in the main,call the pipe() failed\n");

    readfd = pipe_fd[0];
    writefd = pipe_fd[1];

    printf("In the main,First,current a value:%d\n",a );
    int Pid=clone(test2, stack+STACK_SIZE, CLONE_DETACHED|CLONE_FILES, NULL);

    printf("In the main,child PID:%d\n",Pid);
    if(Pid==-1)
    {
        printf("clone error\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    if( (fd = open("abc.txt",O_RDWR)) < 0)
        printf("in the main,open file ./abc.txt failed\n");
    int nbytes = -1;
    char send_string[1024];
    memset(send_string,'\0',1024);

    sprintf(send_string,"the file_fd is:%d",fd);
    if((nbytes = write(writefd,send_string,strlen(send_string))) < 0)
        printf("in the main,send fd failed\n");
    printf("in the main,send %d bytes,the content is----%s\n",nbytes,send_string);







    sleep(10);

    printf("In the main,Second,current a value:%d\n",a );
    printf("yea2");
    exit(0);
}
```

the Problem:

1. the program can execute successfully,
2. but when use the gdb to trace the child process,we get the follow errors:

   ```
   (gdb) b test2 
   Breakpoint 1 at 0x4007d8: file thread.c, line 25.
   (gdb) r
   Starting program: /mnt/hgfs/D/xshell_transmit_folder/thread 
   in the main
   In the main,First,current a value:100
   In the main,child PID:5613
   [New LWP 5613]
   in the main,send 16 bytes,the content is----the file_fd is:9
   [Switching to LWP 5613]

   Breakpoint 1, test2 () at thread.c:25
   25      printf("it is working\n");
   Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64
   (gdb) s
   0x0000003d7d067fd0 in puts () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   (gdb) s
   Single stepping until exit from function puts,
   which has no line number information.

   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   0x0000003d7d0805a1 in __strlen_sse2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   (gdb)
   ```
3. according to the error,the child process get a Segmentation
   fault,because the child process visit a valid address.Does the child process hasn't been created correctlly?
4. Anybody help me? thank Your very much.

Comment: Why do you use `clone` syscall? (It is a tricky low level thing for thread libraries implementors). Can't you use more standard posix-threads or just `fork` ? And AFAIK, `gdb` uses a special library to debug threads... So stick to pthreads ....

Comment: First,thank you very much.
I want use the **clone()** to create a child process which only share the table of file description with parent process,So all the file description created by the parent process can be visiable to child process.
In fact,my current server software use the sendmsg() function to transfer file description form a master process to worker process.But when I do a benchmark,I found that the master process eat too much cpu,and the sys-cpu up to 50%.

Comment: The only reason to use `clone` is for the rare occasion when you are *implementing* a multi-threading library. This is not your case. So please stick to standard libraries like `pthread` ...

Answer (score 1):

GDB is integrated with the threading library which, you are not using. (`clone` is not it).  If you want thread debugging, use `pthread_create`. The `clone` function is not an API intended for user applications, so you are on your own. The meaning of "on your own" includes, but is not limited to, "without a working debugger".  `clone` is a kernel support function for developing user-space threading libs.